# how to manage NFS network consumption on redhat 7.9 server ? for instance to know which process/which user use the most the NFS link?

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I have a server master that contain tools and home directories for all users. then 3 servers are NFS slave connected to the master.
user are connected to the slave and they get their home folder directly from the NFS master. the same for tools.

it means that all files read or written by users are using NFS and the network. local folder are not used by users.

Is there a way to monitor users and process about network and NFS ? I would like to know if a user is doing to much network access because he write a huge file in his home folder that is on the NFS master.

I was told to use nfsiostat but there is no detail about process and users. I was also told to use tcpdump + wireshark but it is not user friendly and I may need to do a lot of work to analysis from the network traffic to the nfs layer to the process layer...

The goal here is to detect the user that has a process that is using a lot of network because he writes a big file in his home folder. I mean I don't want to see that process "nfs" from root is using the network, I want to know which user/process is behind the nfs utilization.

for instance if I could use a program like "top" with a "network" column it could be great but I would be afraid that only the "nfs process" would appear as a big network consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a netflow analyzer ntopng is an open source example of that
https://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/

Comment: thanks. do you think that with this tool I will be able to see exactly which process/user use the nfs traffic or I will be able only to see that an NFS root process will be using the network and then I will need to look for which process is using this nfs process ?

Comment: in the other discussion, i ask quite the same question (out of subject question so I asked it again here) and you answered about optional kernel module netatop that is needed to store information about process and network. is it still usefull to monitor NFS traffic ? or this tool is only about network traffic and won't be able to help me about NFS network traffic ?

Comment: I think it depends on your requirements, if you want to only monitor it for one host or multiple hosts. And if you want to use a central monitoring solution or if are ok doing it on a per machine basis.